# Custom 404 page with vercel.json

Tags: json, vercel

I deployed a landing page with only HTML and CSS and I want to create a custom page for some status codes, for now I'm just going to do the exercise with the 404 page.

In previous years I used Apache servers and it was just adding `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` to the `.htaccess`, now I need to do the same with the `vercel.json`.

I found [this](https://vercel.com/guides/custom-404-page#what-if-i-need-to-name-my-404-file-something-different) in the Vercel guides, but according to the documentation [it](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#legacy/routes) is already deprecated, and when I deploy it, Vercel rejects the deployment, so I used the standard [redirects](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration#project-configuration/redirects) property, but I don't know how to update the old solution.

For now I need any request that returns a 404 response to redirect to the page.

My `vercel.json`:

```json
{
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "redirects": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/status/404/index.html",
            "statusCode": 404
        }
    ]
}
```